# TFS Changeset among 2 TFS Builds

Tags: rest, jenkins, tfs, tfsbuild, tfvc

I have created a TFS build using TFVC as a source code repository. Now, I want to get a full information on all changesets that happened among previous and current build.

Any rest api for this ?

Same sort of thing is available in jenkins using following rest api
http://server:port/job/jobname/lastBuild/api/xml

Comment: What have you tried? A simple web search for "tfs api" will yield the results that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to  [get list of changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#by-item-path) rest api

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version={version}
```

There are multiple options such as *by item path*, *by person*. However it's not able to do what you want directly.

You could use [in a date range](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#in-a-date-range) option. Then you just need to get the **starttime** and **finshtime**  of your previous and current build through this API- [Get build details by Timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#timeline)

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version={version}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get build details - Changes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#changes) in [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview).

Comment: As per API URL, https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version={version} , we need buildId. How to get that ?

Comment: @SalmanPatel Get the build definition ID via https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-list-of-build-definitions first and then get build ID via https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-list-of-builds